# Not able to perform right click is selenium webdriver using JAVA

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Problem Statement :-
 In my application there are 3 frame(say A, B , C) by tag name 
 I am switching to frame B
 After that there are again two frame (say 0,1) by tag name 
 I am switching to iframe 1
 After that I have to perform right click and select 3rd option (which is “Edit”)
When I checked in html tag, my right click option menu is out of 
 My code is as like below

```
 Switching to frame (By tag <Frame>)
 .
 .
 Switching to frame (By tag <iFrame>)
 . 
 . 
 //right click first approach
 WebElement web =driver.findElement(By.id("Filter_List_34425462_RowValue_NameSpan"));
 Actions action= new Actions(driver);
 action.contextClick(web).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).build().perform();
```

My above code is able click right but not selecting 3rd option
 As I mentioned earlier my right click option is out of  tag
 So I tried to switch to to frame B
 Switch to frame(B), But then I am getting error like element unable to locate

I tried switching to active element frame :- It is also giving me same error

Any support will be helpful
 Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

so  how is about the following combination:

actions - for right  clik

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.id("Filter_List_34425462_RowValue_NameSpan"));
new Actions(driver).contextClick(elem).perform();

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

and then try to involve Robot class actions sequence:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Hope this works for you.